# Finding video source in swf file?

Tags: javascript, flash

I'm trying to find the video source behind a flash player. I tried putting the swf file into showmycode but it looks like its only a general player. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to know how to download the a video played via flash player from another website....

Comment: yeah. I want to find the source

Comment: So where does **your source code** come into this?

Comment: They embedded this in an iframe. I wanted to know where they're getting the video stream from.

Comment: So this isn't a problem with your own source code. This question seems to be: How to steal videos from another website. If it isn't then I suggest you edit your question, explain the issue and display any attempts you have made to resolve the issue.

Comment: This isn't my code. I screenshotted it from the site that's currently streaming the video. I tried taking the swf file (seen as the src file) and decompiling it to find where it's getting stream from but it seems like that swf file is only a media player. What I'm looking for is the actual location of the video stream.

Comment: Exactly my point, you want to download the video without the owners permission. You don't own the video or have the rights to download. Are you aware for copyright? StackOverflow is for developers to help each other with real problems, not explain how to steal/download videos from other sites without the owners permission.